# What is the difference between "1 << x" and "pow(2, x)"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, comparison, bit-manipulation

So, while using Unity, there was a point where I had to use bitwise operators. Now, don't get me wrong, I'm fully aware of the usefulness of bitwise operators, and in several cases it cannot be replaced without having to make a bunch of ugly code. The question is more like... What's the difference between a and b, here:

```
double a = 1 << 3;
double b = Math.Pow(2, 3);
```

From my understanding of both functions and binary, in both cases, you end up with a 1 in the fourth position, and this equals 8... What prevents anyone from using Math.pow over a bitwise operator? Would it really change something?

Comment: fine... Assuming I hadn't been a goof, and forgotten that detail... Editing for clarity.

Comment: `1 << 3` is *much faster* (about one CPU tick) than `(int) Math.Pow(2, 3)` (wants *FPU* computation)

Comment: Consider `int.MaxValue << 3` vs `Math.Pow(int.MaxValue, 3);`

Comment: In principle, and considering the example, there is nothing that prevents a smart compiler from generating the same code for both. What actual compilers do may not be that smart however. A more interesting example could be looking the function `double pow2(int n) { return Math.Pow(2, n);}` to see what code is generated.

Comment: When working with larger numbers over 2**53 then it's better/safer to use BigInt and use bitshift (since Math.pow don't support BigInt's) `1n << 160n` or you could use the `1n ** 160n` instead of math.pow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general terms, for most languages:

The pow function is likely to be less efficient, as it essentially general purpose and can raise any number to any power, so cannot be optimized as easily for special cases.

The bit shifting will map directly to a processor level operation.

In  some languages, the compiler would see that the operations have a constant result and use that, however if there is a little more complexity, then the optimization may be missed.

Comment: I understand that difference, yes. But I'm trying to see if I can use the Math.Pow() version if I need to make my code clearer for someone who's not so advanced, and might be interested in learning.

Comment: And `1 << 3` assumes that you are working on a positive integer, small enough not get an overflow. If a 1-bit is moved to the most left bit then you will erroneously get a negative result. So you must test egde cases very carefully when using bit-shift operations. `1 << x` is limited to powers of 2.

Comment: No you really should not use the power function when it is unnecessary. If you need to make that clear, use comments.

Answer (score 11):

> What prevents anyone from using Math.pow over a bitwise operator?
> Would it really change something?

Several things:

1. `(int) Math.Pow(2, y);` is *less readable* than `1 << y`
2. `(int) Math.Pow(2, y)` may bring pesky errors if, say `2.0**10.0` appears to be `1023.99999997`; we have to put even more combersome `(int) (Math.Pow(2, y) + 0.5)`
3. `1 << y` is much faster (about one *CPU* tick) when `Math.Pow(2, y)` wants *FPU* computation
4. `1 << 31` is `-2147483648` which is convenient in bitwise logics. In case of `(int)Math.Pow(2, y)` you can have `OverflowException` thrown
5. `1 << y == 1 << (y % 32)`, so e.g. `1 << 40 == 1 << 8 == 256` which is also convenient.
6. if `y` is *negative* `1 << y` does the same `1 << (y % 32)` thing, e.g. `1 << -31 == 1 << 2 == 4` when `Math.Pow(2, y)` will return tiny `2**y` fraction (`9.31322574615479E-10` in the example)

Finally, the equivalent of `1 << y` is

```
// y >= 0
int result = unchecked((int) (Math.Pow(2, y % 32) + 0.5));
```

Hope, the formula speaks for itself. That's why, please, do not use `Math.Pow` instead of *shifts*